# Prometheus Opsgenie Integration

Tags: devops, prometheus-alertmanager, opsgenie

We use Prometheus alert manager for alerts, we have configured two receivers as attached below, Slack and Opsgenie.
The issue is that we are getting alerts in slack only but we are not receiving alerts in Opsgenie, we use the API keys and it's a working key, we tested it.
Not able to figure why we are not receiving alerts in Opsgenie too.

````
global:
  resolve_timeout: 5m

route:
  group_by: ['alertname']
  group_wait: 10s
  group_interval: 10s
  repeat_interval: 30m
  receiver: 'prod_alert_slack'
  routes:
  # Send severity=page alerts to the pager.
   - match:
      severity: critical|warning|page
     receiver: team-pager
receivers:
- name: team-pager
  opsgenie_configs:
  - responders:
    - name: 'Oncall'
      type: 'team'
    api_key: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
- name: 'prod_alert_slack'
  slack_configs:
  - api_url: https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXXX
    channel: '#prodslack'
    send_resolved: true
    username: '{{ template "slack.default.username" . }}'
    color: '{{ if eq .Status "firing" }}danger{{ else }}good{{ end }}'
    title: '{{ template "slack.default.title" . }}'
    title_link: '{{ template "slack.default.titlelink" . }}'
    pretext: '{{ .CommonAnnotations.summary }}'
    text: |-
      {{ range .Alerts }}
         *Alert:* {{ .Annotations.summary }} - `{{ .Labels.severity }}`
        *Description:* {{ .Annotations.description }}
        *Message:* {{ .Annotations.message }}
        *Details:*
        {{ range .Labels.SortedPairs }} • *{{ .Name }}:* `{{ .Value }}`
        {{ end }}
      {{ end }}
    fallback: '{{ template "slack.default.fallback" . }}'
    icon_emoji: '{{ template "slack.default.iconemoji" . }}'
    icon_url: '{{ template "slack.default.iconurl" . }}'
    #text: "summary: {{ .CommonAnnotations.summary }}\ndescription: {{ .CommonAnnotations.description }}"
inhibit_rules:
  - source_match:
      severity: 'critical'
    target_match:
      severity: 'warning'
    equal: ['alertname', 'dev', 'instance']```
````

Comment: Do you have an example of Prometheus query?

Comment: nvm, the issue was bcoz the API we use is from the basic plan, opsgenie and Prom integrations are for next higher plan from the basic, so this was the reason why it didnt work